# Comma separated script only processing 1 item

Tags: php

I have some code that separates comma delimited entries for inclusion in database. However, it is only inserting 1 item and not say 3 which is what I entered.

If I do var_dump($_SESSION); in NIADMIN.PHP, it shows that all entries have been passed correctly. But, it on inserts 1 item into the database.

I would be grateful if someone could point out the error in my code. Many thanks

BOXINTAKE_RESULTS.PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['box_add'])) {

  if (!empty($_POST['box_add'])) {

    $data       = split(',', $_POST['box_add'][0]);
    $adds       = array();
    $duplicates = array();

    foreach ($data as $val) {
      if ($val != "") {

        if (count(array_unique($data)) < count($data)) {
          echo "<span style=\"color: red; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;\">$val</span>" . ' ' . ' Box input is a duplicate. Each box name must be unqiue.' . '<br />' . 'Please only input boxes that have unique names.';
          echo '<br /><br />';
          echo '<input type="button" value="Return" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;" />';
          return;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT custref FROM boxes WHERE custref='$val' AND customer = '" . $_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr'] . "' Union SELECT item FROM act WHERE item='$val' AND company = '" . $_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr'] . "'";
        $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($qry)) {
          $duplicates[] = $val;
        } else {
          $adds[] = $val;
          $flag   = 1;
        }
      } else {
        $boxerror = '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;color: #ff0000;">' . 'BOX ERROR! ' . '</span>' . '<span style="font-weight:normal;color: #000;background-color:#ffa;">' . 'You must enter a box for intake' . '</span>';
        echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
        echo 'alert("BOX ERROR:\nYou must enter a box for intake.");';
        echo "</script>";
        echo $boxerror;
      }
    }

    if (count($adds)) {
      echo 'You wish to add box(es): ' . '<div style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;overflow:auto !important;height: 100px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid #666; background-color: #fff; padding: 4px;">' . '<span style="font-weight:bold;color: #000;">' . join(', ', $adds) . '</span>' . '</div>' . '<p />';

      //if(count($duplicates) == 0) // add to session only if we have no duplicates
      $_SESSION['box_add'] = $adds; /// change here, do not store $_POST since it can contain duplicates
    }
    if (count($duplicates)) {
      $boxduperror = '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;color: #ff0000;">' . 'BOX ERROR:' . " " . 'Box' . '</span>' . " " . '<span style="font-weight:normal;color: #000;background-color:#ffa;">' . '(' . join(', ', $duplicates) . ')' . " " . 'This box is already in the database' . '</span>';
      echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
      echo 'alert("BOX ERROR:\nThis box is already in the database");';
      echo "</script>";
      echo $boxduperror;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Open in new window

NIADMIN.PHP

```
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['datepick'])) {

    //Box Intake
    $activity = $_SESSION['box_add']; {

        foreach ($activity as $k => $v) {
            // add to action list
            $query = 'INSERT INTO `act` (`service`, `activity`, `department`, `company`,  `address`, `user`, `item`, `destroydate`, `date`, `new`) VALUES (\'' . $service . '\', \'' . $boxsupply . '\', \'' . $deptname . '\', \'' . $customer . '\', \'' . $address . '\', \'' . $user . '\', \'' . strtoupper($v) . '\', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 YEAR), NOW(), \'' . $new . '\');';
            mysql_query($query) or die('Error: ' . $query . 'query failed');
            echo $query;
            echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
            //echo 'alert("BOX INTAKE SUCCESSFULL.\nYou will now be redirected to the requests area.");'; 
            //echo 'location.href = "boxes.php"'; 
            echo "</script>";

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Open in new window

VAR-DUMP $_session from niadmin.php

```
["box_add"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "demo234567" [1]=> string(10) "demo345678" }
```

DATABASE QUERY

Only 1 item not 2 inserted in database

```
INSERT INTO `act` (`service`, `activity`, `department`, `company`, `address`, `user`, `item`, `destroydate`, `date`, `new`) VALUES ('Standard', 'New Intake', 'DEMO', 'DEMO', 'Demo Road Anytown EC4 5RT', 'Demo User', 'DEMO234567', '2024-08-22', NOW(), '1');
```

Comment: have you enable error reporting?

Comment: `split()` is no longer available in php7, I would recommend you use `explode()` instead. Same goes for `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @Fast Yes and no errors are being reported.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I a using 5.4. Thanks